# How to send message with attachment using GMAIL API without access token or redirecting

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I can send an email with and without attachment using GMAIL API. My only problem is that it looks like when I want to send an attachment I need an accesstoken. This is not good as right after the user filled out the email form, attached the file and clicked the Send button, I need to somehow save all the data (like sending them in the state parameter?), load [gmail's authentication link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent), reload the page on redirect, retrieve the accesstoken from the url that's now filled with a lot of things totally irrelevant for the user, retrieve my data from the url and send the email at last.

According to the docs the state parameter is used to retrieve data after the redirect so I need to send the `to`, `cc`, `subject`, `base64 encoded msg`, `contenttype` and `filename` variables.

What other options do I have?

```
function getAccessToken() {
        window.location = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=' + scopes + '&state=' + 'hello' + '&redirect_uri=https://skeebdo.com/quickstart.html' + '&response_type=token' + '&client_id=' + clientId;
    }

//Now when the page gets redirected and back I need to read the accesstoken and state parameter from the url.
var accesstoken = '';
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf("access_token=") > 0) {
    var at_starts = url.indexOf("access_token=");
    var tokentype_starts = url.indexOf("&token_type=");
    accesstoken = url.substring((at_starts + 13), tokentype_starts);
    if (url.indexOf("state=") > 0) {
        //get to, cc, subject, msg, contenttype, filename, base64 encoded file
    }
}

function sendEmail() { //Send email

        var to = $("#compose-to").val();
        var cc = $("#compose-cc").val();
        var subject = $("#compose-subject").val();
        var message = editor.getData();

        if (contenttype != null && contenttype != "" && contenttype.length > 0) {
            //we got an attachment!

                var pngData = base64_image;

                var mail = 
                  'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="foo_bar_baz"\n' +
                  'MIME-Version: 1.0\n' +
                  'to: ' + to + '\n' +
                  'cc: ' + cc + '\n' +
                  'subject: ' + subject + '\n\n' +

                  '--foo_bar_baz\n' +
                  'Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"\n' +
                  'MIME-Version: 1.0\n' +
                  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n' +

                  message + '\n\n' +

                  '--foo_bar_baz\n' +
                  'Content-Type: ' + contenttype + '\n' +
                  'MIME-Version: 1.0\n' +
                  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n' +
                  'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' + filename + '\n\n' +

                  pngData + '\n\n' +

                  '--foo_bar_baz--';


                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                    url:"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?uploadType=multipart",
                    contentType: "message/rfc822",                    
                    async: true,
                    data: mail,
                    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accesstoken); 
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                        ShowNotification("success", "Message Sent!");
                    },
                    error:function(xhr,err){
                        alert("readyState:"+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status)
                        alert(xhr.responseText)
                        if (xhr.status == "401") { //get or refresh accesstoken
                            alert("Ujra kell kerni az accesstokent");
                            getAccessToken();
                        }

                    }
                });
            } else {
                //No attachment
                sendTextMessage(
                {
                    'To': to,
                    'Cc': cc,
                    'Subject': subject
                },
                message);
            }

        }   
    }


function sendTextMessage(headers_obj, message, callback) {

        var email = '';

        for(var header in headers_obj)
        email += header += ": "+headers_obj[header]+"\r\n";
        email += 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n';
        email += "\r\n" + message;

        var sendRequest = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
            'userId': 'me',
            'resource': {
            'raw': window.btoa(email).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_')
            }
        });
        return sendRequest.execute(callback);
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered to first get the access token, and then let the user fill-in the e-mail? In this case, redirecting is not such a big deal.

Comment: The access token is valid for 1 hour, so interrupting the session is bad UX

Comment: Oauth2 implementation typically should support refreshing an access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the Access Token only once, after which you can use the refresh token to regenerate access token once it has expired.

Comment: Thanks for idea, I seem to have ignored this from the documentation. I managed to do this at last, solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674841/unable-to-get-access-and-refresh-token-after-authenticating-with-google-api/39677051#39677051