# Unable to get access and refresh token after authenticating with Google API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-js-client

I followed [this awesome tutorial](https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/google-oauth-2-enable-your-application-to-access-data-from-a-google-user/) to get the access and refresh tokens once the user logged in with their google account, but I always this response when I call `GetAccessCode()`:

```
{
   "error": "invalid_request"
}
```

Here's my code:

```
var url = window.location.href;

if (url.indexOf("code=") > 0) { //Once the user signed in with Google
    var code_starts = url.indexOf("code=");
    var code = url.substring((code_starts + 5), url.length);
    alert("Code= " + code);
    GetAccessTokens(code);
} else if (url.indexOf("access_token=") > 0) { //Get the tokens, but I never get this far
    var at_starts = url.indexOf("access_token=");
    var exp_starts = url.indexOf("expires_in=");
    var access_token = url.substring((at_starts + 13), exp_starts);
    alert("AT= " + access_token);

    var rt_starts = url.indexOf("refresh_token=");
    var id_starts = url.indexOf("id_token=");
    var refresh_token = url.substring((rt_starts + 14), id_starts);
    alert("RT= " + refresh_token);
} else {
    GetAccessCode(); //If user opens the page, show him the consent screen
}

function GetAccessCode() {
   window.location = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com/quickstart.html' + '&response_type=code' + '&client_id=' + clientId + '&scope=' + scopes + '&approval_prompt=force' + '&access_type=offline';
}

function GetAccessTokens(code) {
    window.location = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?code=' + code + '&client_id=' + clientId + '&client_secret=' + clientSecret + '&redirect_uri=https://mywebsite.com/quickstart.html' + '&grant_type=authorization_code';
}
```

Here I receive the invalid_request error.

I tried to get the tokens via an ajax request to not have to redirect the page again (bad UX):

```
    var red = 'https://mywebsite.com/quickstart.html';
    var options = {
       url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "json",
       data: "code=code&client_id=clientId&client_secret=clientSecret&redirect_uri=red&grant_type=authorization_code",
        complete: function (e) {
            alert(e);
            alert(e.status);
        },
    };
    $.ajax(options);
}
```

I tried it with headers, too:

```
headers: { "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
```

And I tried it this way, too:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    type: "post",
    datatype:"json",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    async : true,
    data: {code:code, client_id:clientId, client_secret:clientSecret, redirect_uri:'https://mywebsite.com/quickstart.html', grant_type:'authorization_code'},
    success: function(response){
        alert(response); //I never get this
        var json = $.parseJSON(response);
    } 
})
.fail(function(err) {
    alert("error" + err); //I get [Object object]
});
```

And a few other stuff, too.
Oh, and all the parameters have the correct value.

Any ideas?

Ps: The [oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) shows that the corrent token url is `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` but when I use it I get `Not found` in the browser.

Comment: Hi, you should use the console.log function instead of alert to have more debugging information (instead of having [Object object], you'll have the real object (its keys and values) displayed in the browser javascript console). You can open the Chrome Dev Tools via the F12 key on Google Chrome (not sure how to access the dev tools on other browsers). This should give you more details on the error you get from the Google API ;)

Answer (score 4):

After 3 days I did it. Thanks for the console.log tip, @Brunt!

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
            type: "post",
            datatype:"json",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            async : true,
            data: {code:code, client_id:clientId, client_secret:clientSecret, redirect_uri:'https://mywebsite.com/quickstart.html', grant_type:'authorization_code'},
            success: function(response){
                console.log("Response: " + response);
                console.log("AT: " + response['access_token']);
                console.log("RT: " + response['refresh_token']);

                access_token = response['access_token'];
                refresh_token = response['refresh_token'];
            }
        })
        .fail(function(err) {
            alert("error" + err); //[Object object]
            console.log("error" + err);
        });
```